# What are the pros and cons of using nest rest streaming APIs over rest APIs?

Tags: nest-api

Nest supports rest streaming and rest APIs for fetching thermostat and structure data. On rest API calls, they have limit of 1 API call/sec and rest streaming apis poll data every 30 secs (pls correct me if i am wrong)? What are other pros and cons of using nest rest apis over nest rest streaming apis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speed is the mane advantage, the response time of the various methods from fastest to slowest is:

1. Firebase (ie WebSockets, which send change notifications, network latency is the biggest overhead)
2. REST streaming (setup and tear down connection on change and timeout)
3. REST polling (setup and tear down connection on each poll, can't be any faster than polling interval, which is below the rate limit)

Answer (score 2):

REST streaming APIs don't make a request every 30 seconds; your client makes a single streaming API call and Firebase responds, but doesn't close the connection, so that it can send 'change' data when available. Firebase will send occasional keepalives if there is no change data to send, so that your client does not close the connection. I have not managed to find any documentation of how frequently Firebase sends keepalives but (eg) Twitter sends them every 30 seconds.